# TypeBuilder allows defining two fields with the same name

Tags: .net, clr, reflection.emit

I am working on an interactive compiler in my spare time, and I found that I can define a type using a `TypeBuilder` which defines two fields with the same name (and the type apparently emits and runs its initializer, where these static fields are initialized, just fine) . See my watch window:

[image]

I find this odd: what practical purpose could a type with two fields of the same name have? Is this really "legal" per the CLR specification (would be interested in a reference), or is this undefined or illegal behavior that the `TypeBuilder` should perhaps have not allowed?

Comment: A practical reason to use same name for two different fields is for code obfuscation.

Comment: I'd expect it to throw at the moment of the class being loaded by metadata system. If it did not, then it's probably legal. Anyways, I'd suppose that CLR uses handles to identify fields/methods/properties, not names. So, as long as everything is generated and using handles or offsets to correct members, it should be ok. But, if something refers to it by-name, like via DLR, then it'll probably throw AmbiguousMatch.

Comment: I've stumbled upon [this social.msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed1a92bc-da1e-4a75-a12a-05c6b205ca25/reflection-with-typebuilder-adding-duplicate-field-in-a-type) where it's stated that this is 'by design' of TypeBuilder and that 'you have to take care of it'. There's still no mention about it being illegal at the CLR layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in §I.8.5.2 of the [ECMA-335 CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#52):

> Generally, names are not unique. Names are collected into groupings called
>   *scopes*. Within a scope, a name can refer to multiple entities as long as they are of different *kinds* (methods, fields, nested types, properties, and events) or have different signatures.
>
> *CLS Rule 5*: All names introduced in a CLS-compliant scope shall be distinct independent of kind, except where the names are identical and resolved via overloading. That is, while the CTS allows a single type to use the same name for a method and a field, the CLS does not.

The way I understand this, it means that you can have two different fields with the same name in the same type, but they have to have a different signature, i.e. different type. So, if you have two fields `string x` and `int x`, that's okay according to the CLI specification. It's not okay according to the Common Language Specification (CLS), but that's basically just a set of rules that makes language interoperability easier.

On the other hand, a type with two fields with the same name and type is not legal and if you run PEVerify on an assembly with a type like that, it indeed fails verification:

> [MD]: Error: Field has a duplicate, token=0x04000002. [token:0x04000001]
>   [MD]: Error: Field has a duplicate, token=0x04000001. [token:0x04000002]

For some reason, it seems the CLR does not make this check, so it allows such invalid types. The C# compiler is also able to handle such types, it seems it chooses one of the two fields and uses that.